# /review tab not accessible on a private beta

Tags: bug, review, private-beta

The /review tab isn't accessible on Private Betas to those with less than 350 reputation. However, if one manually types in the /review, then one can see the review tab, and access the close and reopen queues. It seems that if you can access any of the queues, you should be able to see the review button at the top bar.

Comment: I actually don't think the Close/Reopen review queue should be available to anyone in private beta, at least for the first week.  The purpose of the review queues is to help with housekeeping and it is hard to do the clean up when you are still deciding what is on or off topic.

Comment: That would be an option, but I would like to see consistency at least...

Comment: IIRC everyone in the private beta can vote to close/reopen, which  includes (not sure) the access to the review queues. Adding the /review link to things you have access to is a good idea.