# Add the “review” link in the topbar on "private beta" sites if I am able to review any review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, top-bar, private-beta

I committed and joined http://relationships.stackexchange.com in private beta. As per private beta privilege page casting close and reopen votes requires only 1 reputation. So anyone is able to access close votes and reopen votes review queues. But there is no link of the review page in the top bar or anywhere. So I thought I am not able to access *any* review queue. I opened the review page by typing the URL manually (to see review statistics for curiosity). But I found that I can access close & reopen votes review queues.

> [image]

Probably I won't be able to access any review queue if I have less than 350 and the site goes to public beta. But during private beta off topics, unclear, or closable questions are likely to come. So it is very important to close/reopen them during private beta.

So can we please add the "review" link in the top bar if I am able to review some queues?

Comment: We got the same with ai.stackexchange.com private beta.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/review tab not accessible on a private beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202700/review-tab-not-accessible-on-a-private-beta)

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto no. It is the other way around.

Comment: The other one was first.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto This one has a dev answer, while the other one is unanswered.

Comment: Good point. Forgot the other didn't have an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed rolling out with next build - rev `2014.4.18.2176` on meta and rev `2014.4.18.1558` on sites.

The link should appear as soon as you have the minimal required rep for any of the review queues enabled on the site.