# Link to "review" doesn't show up in the top bar on child metas for certain amounts of rep

Tags: bug, review, top-bar

The situation: as of now, I have 781 rep on [Japanese.SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) (a beta site). This grants me access to the First Posts, Late Answers, Close Votes, and Reopen Votes queues on main, as well as [the Close Votes and Reopen Votes queues on meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brutx.png). On main, I have a link to "review" in the top bar. On meta, however, [I do not have a link to "review"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cioYV.png). If I go directly to [the /review URL](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/review), though, I can access the queues just fine.

This appears to be a bug of some sort - once I have access to at least one review queue on meta (which happens at 500 rep on beta sites), I should see the "review" link in the top bar.

Note that there seems to be some amount of rep between 781 and 6331 that causes the "review" link to appear on meta - I have 6331 rep on [Anime.SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/), and [*do* see the "review" link on its meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zduNK.png).

Comment: It's by-design that they don't show up at low rep, but the link should show up once you have enough to use any queue. Sounds like the meta-site link isn't properly using the beta sites' reduced rep requirements, maybe?

Comment: Related but for *private beta*: [Add the “review” link in the topbar on “private beta” sites if I am able to review any review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217206/187824)

Comment: This might be accidently hard-coded to 2000 rep (the value needed on graduated meta sites), which would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: marking as a duplicate since it was part of a larger problem, implementing the original also fixes this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 2012 the review link code has been checking for the edit privilege on meta sites. Accidentally the rep limit is equal for both on some metas and is 2000 for edit on other as @Qantas94Heavy pointed out.

This is weird on sites like [japanese.se.meta](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) where the difference is huge - `350` (review) vs. `1000` (edit). I'm investigating what the background on that is.